# Movement of body after applying weld joint

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx, body

I have two rectangular bodies. I've applied `Weldjoint` successfully on these bodies.
I want to move that joined body by applying linear impulse. After weld joint, these two bodies becomes single body right? How do I apply force/impulse on the joined body?

I am using Box2D with LibGDX.

I've tried this:

```
polygon1.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-5, 0), polygon1.getWorldCenter(), true);
```

I thought that if I move `polygon1` then `polygon2` will also move due to my weld joint
but it is not working properly.

Why don't they move together after being welded?

below is my code.

```
package com.test.box2d;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.ChainShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.joints.WeldJointDef;

public class WeldJointTest extends Game{

    World world;
    Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    Body polygon1, polygon2;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        world = new World(new Vector2(0, -10), true);
        debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 10, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 10);

        //body def
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bodyDef.position.set(-20, -8f);

        //shape
        PolygonShape polygonShape = new PolygonShape();
        polygonShape.setAsBox(2, 2);

        //fixture def
        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.density = 1;
        fixtureDef.restitution = .2f;
        fixtureDef.friction = .3f;
        fixtureDef.shape = polygonShape;

        polygon1 = world.createBody(bodyDef);
        polygon1.createFixture(fixtureDef);

        // body def
        bodyDef.position.set(-16, -8f);

        polygon2 = world.createBody(bodyDef);
        polygon2.createFixture(fixtureDef);

        //floor body def
        bodyDef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
        bodyDef.position.set(-40, -50);

        // floor shape
        ChainShape chainShape = new ChainShape();
        chainShape.createChain(new Vector2[]{new Vector2(-100, 40), new Vector2(100, 40)});

        //fixture def
        fixtureDef.shape = chainShape;

        world.createBody(bodyDef).createFixture(fixtureDef);


        WeldJointDef weldJointDef = new WeldJointDef();
        weldJointDef.bodyA = polygon1;
        weldJointDef.bodyB = polygon2;
        weldJointDef.localAnchorA.set(new Vector2(4, 0));
//      weldJointDef.localAnchorB.set(polygon2.getWorldCenter());

        world.createJoint(weldJointDef);
        /*DistanceJointDef distanceJointDef = new DistanceJointDef();
        distanceJointDef.bodyA = polygon1;
        distanceJointDef.bodyB = polygon2;
        distanceJointDef.length = 25;

        world.createJoint(distanceJointDef);*/

        chainShape.dispose();
        polygonShape.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
        world.step(1/60f, 8, 3);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputProcessor() {

            @Override
            public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {

                switch (keycode) {
                case Keys.LEFT:
                    polygon1.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-5, 0), polygon1.getWorldCenter(), true);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

        });

    }

}
```

from main method.

```
LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.title = "Body Movement Test";
        cfg.useGL20 = false;
        cfg.width = 800;
        cfg.height = 480;
```

Comment: What does "it is not working properly" mean? Describe exactly what happens. Please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: Isn't a weld joint the same as any other joint - the bodies are still 'separate'?

Comment: I've edited my question and add my code.Please look at this.
After pressing LEFT key... it is not moving. What I am thinking is 2 bodies have been joint each other. If i apply force on first body, second body should also move .
AM I thinking correctly or not???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've managed to reproduce your problem - basically your friction is too high/your impulse not enough.

Change your impulse from (-5, 0) to something like (-50, 0), and/or lower your friction coefficient. Seems to work...

Also, on a side note, I wouldn't recommend instantiating and setting your InputProcessor every frame - do it once in your create() method (unless you have reason).

Comment: thanx.. and i've done that.
but, now my next problem is how to calculate the center of mass of combined body.

Comment: You can calculate the combined centre of mass very easily - Google will help you (for eg [see this page](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/cm.html))